# Multiple usercontrols have one namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, namespaces

I have multiple usercontrols in my asp.net website ,I define for every user control a single name space like below:
Add document user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddDocument.ascx.cs" Inherits="DMS.UI.Users.Controls.AddDocument" %>
```

C# code behind:

```
namespace DMS.UI.Users.Controls
{
    public partial class AddDocument : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

AddSubversion  Usercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddSubversion.ascx.cs" Inherits="DMS.UI.Users.Controls.AddSubversion" %>
```

c# code behind:

```
namespace DMS.UI.Users.Controls
{
    public partial class AddSubversion : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

now I need to work with other usercontrols in one user control, like this:

```
AddSubversion ucAddSubversion = (AddSubversion)this.Parent.Parent.FindControl("ucAddSubversion");
```

but program not recognize that all usercontrols are in one namespace.Why and how to solve this ?

thanks a lot

Comment: If you'd like to work this way I would encourage you to use custom controls instead of user controls.

Comment: Have you added `using DMS.UI.Users.Controls;` at the top of the file?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : I have more flexibility for Html Design in User Controls , ...  unfortunately I have little flexibility in custom controls

Comment: @TimSchmelter : all usercontrols are in one namespace ,no need to add using! but even if I add using , other usercontrols not recognized

Comment: @minamorsali You've even more flexibility. The main drawback is you need to code HTML using C#.....

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : there are a lot of page with a lot of html codes.I can't code using c#... is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define namespaces for usercontrols are different from namespaces for classes. if we want to use one usercontrol in another , only way is to Register that user control in another user control.even if two user controls were in one namespace ,without Register visual studio (2010) we can not access that user controls and its public properties...

```
<%@ Register Src="AddSubversion.ascx" TagName="AddSubversion" TagPrefix="uc5" %>
```